Understanding Factory Design Pattern in Python
The Python version of the Factory pattern in Refactoring Guru is:
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Creator(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def factory_method(self) -> Product:
        pass

    def some_operation(self) -> str:
        product = self.factory_method()
        result = f"Creator: The same creator's code has just worked with {product.operation()}"
        return result

class ConcreteCreator1(Creator):
    def factory_method(self) -> Product:
        return ConcreteProduct1()


class ConcreteCreator2(Creator):
    def factory_method(self) -> Product:
        return ConcreteProduct2()


class Product(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def operation(self) -> str:
        pass

class ConcreteProduct1(Product):
    def operation(self) -> str:
        return "{Result of the ConcreteProduct1}"


class ConcreteProduct2(Product):
    def operation(self) -> str:
        return "{Result of the ConcreteProduct2}"


def client_code(creator: Creator) -> None:
    print(f"Client: I'm not aware of the creator's class, but it still works.\n"
          f"{creator.some_operation()}", end="")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client_code(ConcreteCreator1())
    client_code(ConcreteCreator2())

Honestly, I'm a bit hesitant to ask this here because it looks like a very simple question, but here I go:

What's the benefit of introducing the ConcreteCreatorX class as opposed to passing the Product type directly like below?

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any

class Product(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def operation(self) -> Any:
        pass

class ConcreteProduct1(Product):
    def operation(self) -> str:
        return "{Result of the ConcreteProduct1}"


class ConcreteProduct2(Product):
    def operation(self) -> str:
        return "{Result of the ConcreteProduct2}"
    
def client_code(product: Product) -> None:
    print(f"Client: I'm not aware of the creator's class, but it still works.\n"
          f"{product.operation()}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client_code(ConcreteProduct1())
    client_code(ConcreteProduct2())


In both cases, client_code expects some type that implements an operation method. The Product type is already providing such method in an abstract way so that each Product can implement its own variant of the method. So, from the  client_code's perspective I see no difference in using one or the other.
Now, there is a difference between the two codes: the first example (actual Factory pattern example) is delegating the instantiation of each ConcreteProductX class to the ConcreteCreatorX class (which I understand is the whole point of the pattern).
We are separating concerns that way, sure, if we want to modify the factory method we don't need to modify directly the Product class. I can see the benefit in case we want to modify the factory_method to do something else apart from instantiating the ConcreteProductX class, like notifying something somewhere, keeping track of how many products are created, etc. But then wouldn't we be breaking the Single Responsibility Principle? Because now the Creator is not only responsible for creating a product. In other words, should it be qualified to be called Creator?
So I guess my question could be reformulated in a more precise way:

Is there any benefit of using Creator and ConcreteCreatorX classes that does not involve breaking the Single Responsability Principle?


Does this answer your question? What's the difference between Factory Method implementations?

Mmm not really, I guess my question would be answered with an example showing that introducing a Creator allows to extend the program's functionality producing less breaking changes than the second example in my post, for the same new functionality @jaco0646

This kind of design is required when you can't pass a function itself as an argument, only an object that provides the method you want to call.
Idiomatic Python would be even simpler:
type Creator = Callable[[], str]

def client_code(creator: Creator) -> None:
    print(f"Client: I'm not aware of the creator's class, but it still works.\n"
          f"{creator()}", end="")


def factory1() -> str:
    ...

def factory2() -> str:
    ...

client_code(factory1)
client_code(factory2)


Thanks for your answer, indeed, I actually thought this would be simpler in python, that's why I am asking this question here too. I want to understand why the factory design pattern (using classes) has such "elevated" status compared to other abstractions like the one you posted

Because most of the descriptions you  read are tailored towards languages that require such classes to implement, because they don't support first-class functions. Design patterns are sometimes described as ways to work around the limitations of your language, and Python simply lacks the limitations that makes the common description of the factory pattern necessary.

In Gang of Four's "Design Patterns" this pattern is known as "Abstract Factory" and has been designed for pure Object Oriented programming language, back when it was not possible to use functional-style features in OOP.
The code that you have found is the implementation of the Abstract Factory just as it was designed in that book, in 1994.
Now it is pretty common for simple use cases to use arrow functions, lambdas or callables to implement a factory, even in languages like Java or C# that are mainly OOP.
There are still use cases where you need to write a class hiererchy to implement the factory. Typically these use cases require your software to use dependency injection and inversion of control and your "Product" class to need arguments that should come from the IoC container, plus other kind of arguments that cannot come from IoC container ('client code' is a good example of this second kind).
Take a look at this pseudo code:
Product:
   constructor(AService service, String clientCode)
   method1(...):...


ProductFactory:
   constructor(AService service): ....
   createProduct(String clientCode):
      return new Product(service, clientCode)

AClient:
   constructor(ProductFactory factory):....
   someMethod():
      client_code = "..."
      product = factory.createProduct(client_code)
      product.method1()

The way to solve this problem is that you have a factory class that gets all the Product arguments that need to come from the IoC container from the IoC container and a factory method (which is "createProduct" in the example) that gets the rest of Product arguments as method arguments.
